# Dealing with excessive sweat in the hands while playing squash

Tags: equipment, squash

I started playing squash again after several years of hiatus. It is great fun but one thing that really bothers me is that my old and faithful racket slips in my hand during some occasions. This is especially frustrating when serving the ball and under no stress whatsoever.

I thought about having a small towel with me but it feels silly to run around the court with a towel and wipe of sweat after every second rally.

I can imagine this being an issue that other people face as well. Is it simply a matter of getting a new grip or racket?

Comment: How old's the grip on your racket?

Answer (score 5):

I coach high school squash and run into this occasionally.

The most common thing players do is to wipe their hands along the sole of their shoe, much like you'll see [basketball players doing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/5868/11530) sometimes.

A second practice that I've seen but that I discourage in my players is to drag/swipe one's palm along the wall. It works, but it's pretty rude in my book.

Comment: Re: last sentence, don't pros do that all the time as well?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have any sway with them =)

Comment: heheh, fair enough.. :) but I was just thinking how something that's done so casually on pro level would be considered rude

Comment: Yeah, but practice courts at a HS aren't getting cleaned in between matches for the camera crew to get good shots--we're lucky that the walls get cleaned up once a season. They get pretty grody if everyone's man*hand*ling them =\

Comment: Good point, and a nice pun :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are not already, use sweatbands on the wrists to prevent it running down from your arms to your hands.

If the racquet is older, the grip may need replacing. Consider using one moulded to your hand or with ridging that relies less on friction alone.

Finally, obtain advice from an exercise professional about how to develop the muscles in your forearm to grip more strongly and consistently.

Comment: My hands do not sweat much, but rest of my body more than makes up for it. Sweat is literally pouring onto my hand via the arm, so after 10 minutes of play, the racket became unbearably slippery. Using sweatbands completely eliminated the issue as it stops the sweat from getting to the palm.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. I solve it by using either [TournaGrip](https://www.squashsource.com/tourna-grip/) or [Yonex Super Grap](https://www.squashsource.com/yonex-squash-grips/) overgrips. (Overgrips are wrapped on top of the factory grip.)

Those are the only two grips I'd use for an important match -- everything else is too slippery in my hand.

My friend, who also has sweaty hands, swears by [Dry Grip](https://www.squashsource.com/dry-grip/), which is an antiperspirant cream. I'm happy enough with the overgrips that I haven't ventured into the cream situation, but it's another option, and it can be used in combination with the overgrips.